# How to execute raw queries using sqlx?

Tags: go, sqlx

Using [sqlx](https://github.com/jmoiron/sqlx) as my database adapter, I'd like to run queries on user profiles based on user-submitted POST data. There are several parameters like `age`, `sex` and `location` and many more.

So for example if only `age` value is submitted by the user, the query should looks like:

```
var profiles []model.Profile
q:= "SELECT *  FROM profile WHERE age = ?"
err = database.SQL.Select(&profiles, q, age)
if err != nil {
    log.Println(err)
}
```

As you can see, since the query can not be built dynamically, this method is not flexible enough and becomes so verbose to account for all possible variations.

What I want is to construct query based on the input data then just feed the raw query to sqlx.

Something like this pseudo code:

```
q:= `SELECT *  FROM profile WHERE 
      age > 25   AND sex="f" AND location="London"`
    err = database.SQL.ExecRaw(&profiles, q)
```

How can I achieve this in sqlx?
I have looked at the docs but could not figure out how to do so.

Comment: There's no methods like `Where`, that could add filter condition to query, in sqlx. Only way to do it is write your own method that will be generating sql string based on user input.

Comment: How would what you're looking for differ from `Select`, other than not using parameters, which puts you at risk for the most common security flaw (SQL injection)?

Comment: @Adrian, The input data are already sanitized. So that is not a concern here.

Comment: @GrigoriyMikhalkin I have no clue how to do so.

Comment: So not using parameters *is* the only difference? Then just don't use parameters. `Select` doesn't prevent you from putting literals in your query.

Comment: @Adrian that's great. Never thought that I could! Please answer and I'll accept.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you don't want to use parameters, don't use parameters. Select doesn't prevent you from putting literals in your query.